# what is the meaning of online: true option?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

I found a code in stackoverflow.

```
def after_sign_up_or_signin_path_for(resource)  
  resource.update_all(online: true)  
  dashboard_url
end
```

since this question should not be asked in stackoverflow, but I googled and researched for hours, but unable to find meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class

`update_all` just updates all records in a table - in this case, whichever table is represented by `resource`. In this case, you're updating all records to set the `online` column to `true`.

Basically, if you've just signed in, the application wants to mark you as online.

Comment: he he he, my question was really ridiculous, I was thinking that 'online: true' is a rails built-in options, but actually it's a column in table. Thanks  joshua.paling for clarifying.